Messing up scaling on UI on Unity
I don't know how to use Scale while securing the position at the same time.
I am messing it up. When I would scale up, either it will come out big if I choose Scale Anchor or too small If I use Corner as Anchor Point.
If I scale based on Position Anchor:(small version):

Big version with Corner Anchor:

Big version with Scale Anchor:

Tried using other types of anchors but none seems to solve my  problem
